# why do I see the source code (html) of some web pages?

Tags: html, firefox

Most web pages are normally parsed and of course I don't see tags like `<html>` or `<a href=>`.

But, when I open some web sites, the source code pops up.

Try this

http://mediacomp-jes.googlecode.com/svn-history/r68/jes/JESHelp/auxHelp/mediaToolsOverview.html

So I saved this web page and reopened locally using firefox, everything seems normal again.

any reasons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're viewing the file in an SVN repository browser.  They must have the encoding for the documents in these directories set to render as plain text.  I am using chrome and saw the same thing.  It's by design in this case.

Comment: thanks for the super fast reply! I learned something today :)

Answer (score 3):

As everybody says, it is the server side (Apache) configuration. You can confirm this by issuing HEAD request.

```
curl -I http://mediacomp-jes.googlecode.com/svn-history/r68/jes/JESHelp/auxHelp/mediaToolsOverview.html
```

returns

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 29 Dec 2011 00:27:49 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Thu, 16 Oct 2008 18:13:57 GMT
ETag: "2//jes/JESHelp/auxHelp/mediaToolsOverview.html"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Expires: Thu, 29 Dec 2011 00:30:49 GMT
Content-Length: 1802
Content-Type: text/plain
Cache-Control: public, max-age=180
Age: 0
```

Notice that Content-Type says "text/plain"

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at a svn repository, and the response type is text/plain instead of text/html, so the browser renders it as text instead of html

Answer (score 2):

SVN or not the important for the browser is the header `Content-Type` - the most of the pages are rendered as html, no matter the extension or absence of such, because of the header. Another effect obviously will be that JavaScript won't be executed.

About the Content-Type [<sup>ietf</sup>](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1049) and MIME types list [<sup>Wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mime_type)

Header `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` - rendered

```
lynx -head -dump http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662745/why-do-i-see-the-source-code-html-of-some-web-pages
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
Content-Length: 41163
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Thu, 29 Dec 2011 00:26:08 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 29 Dec 2011 00:25:08 GMT
Vary: *
Date: Thu, 29 Dec 2011 00:25:08 GMT
Connection: close
```

Header `Content-Type: text/plain` - displayed as text

```
lynx -head -dump http://mediacomp-jes.googlecode.com/svn-history/r68/jes/JESHelp/auxHelp/mediaToolsOverview.html
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Thu, 29 Dec 2011 00:26:00 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Thu, 16 Oct 2008 18:13:57 GMT
ETag: "2//jes/JESHelp/auxHelp/mediaToolsOverview.html"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Expires: Thu, 29 Dec 2011 00:29:00 GMT
Content-Length: 1802
Content-Type: text/plain
Cache-Control: public, max-age=180
Age: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because this page has been encoded and then put in the page. So if you look at the page source your see it is written like `&lt;html&gt; &lt;head&gt; &lt;title&gt;` obviously because some one wants to show the page mark up. Nothing wrong with your browser etc

Comment: like batkins also comments this is an svn repo so its prob turned on in a setting to render the mark up